# Simplifying two jQuery functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there one function that would do the job of both of these (and anything that continued the format)?

```
   $("#1A").hover(function(){
         $(".route1A").stop().fadeToggle(500);
      });

  $("#1B").hover(function(){
      $(".route1B").stop().fadeToggle(500);
      });
```

The result would look something like below, where __ is code for 'these are the same':

```
$("#__").hover(function(){
  $(".route__").stop().fadeToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the selector for `.hover()` to include `#1A, #1B, etc.` and then just grab the id off of the element that triggered the hover event to create your class selector, like so:

```
$("#1A, #1B").hover(function(){
   $(".route" + this.id).stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
var names = ["1A", "1B"]; //Extend as needed
for(var i=0; i<letters.length; ++i) {
    $("#" + names[i]).hover(function() {
        $(".route" + names[i]).stop().fadeToggle(500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [multi-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). This will bind the event handler to all selectors included.

```
$("#1A, #1B").hover(function(){
    $(".route" + this.id).stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```